# Creating a REST API with SLIM Framework. Keeping in line with REST but providing the correct view

Tags: php, rest, slim

I am trying to wrap my head around how to create a RESTful API with SLIM. I understand REST and I have a good understanding of slim but what I can understand is how to render the correct view templates.

This is a typical REST API

```
$app->get('/wines', 'getWines');
$app->get('/wines/:id',  'getWine');
$app->post('/wines', 'addWine');
$app->put('/wines/:id', 'updateWine');
$app->delete('/wines/:id',   'deleteWine');
```

Now what I don't understand is if all the routes have the same URL how can you render the correct view template. The first **GET** request displays all the wines. The next **GET** displays only the wine with the specified id. Now this is where my understanding falters. When I want to add a wine I write a route that reacts differently to either a **GET** or **POST** request.

```
$app->map('/wines', function() {
    echo "I respond to multiple HTTP methods!";
})->via('GET', 'POST');
```

So for the get request I want show a form so I can enter a new wine but as the URL is the same as getting *all* the wines and they are both **GET** requests how can I render the correct template.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a form to the response  to `GET /wines/` which describes the `POST /wines/` and you should add links for each of the `GET /wines/:id`-s.

You can use [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) for the links, and some [ad-hoc solution](https://github.com/inf3rno/HAL-forms) for the form. If you want a more sophisticated solution, you can use [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/) with JSON-LD.